Dash Python: Layout Function combined with @Callback
page1.py
import ... .layout as layout 

import dash

import pandas as pd

dash.register_page(__name__, path='/page_one') # I have an app.py which is running the app
       
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                             'B': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})
df = df.reset_index()

layout = layout.update_page(df)

layout.py
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import dcc,html,Input, Output, callback
from dash import dash_table
import dash_daq as daq

def update_page(arg1):
    layout = html.Div(children = [
                    dbc.Col(daq.NumericInput(
                            id='my-numeric-input-1',
                            min=0,
                            max=100,
                            value=0,
                            label='Update Table',
                            labelPosition='top',
                            style={"paddingBottom": 15}),)

                   ,html.Br(),

                   dash_table.DataTable(
                       id='table',
                       data=arg1.to_dict('records'),
                       columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in arg1.columns])

     ])

    return layout
@callback(
    Output('table', 'data'),
    Input('my-numeric-input-1', 'value'),
    )
def updateTable(x):
    if x>0:
        #ERROR here does not recognise the veriable arg1##

        arg1.iloc[1,1] = arg1.iloc[1,1]*x #I.e. do stuff to the table
        
    return arg1.to_dict('records')    
return arg1.to_dict('records') 

Goal:
I have a simple dataframe that is being produced in page1.py and i want to pass that df into a layout function called 'update_page' that is created in layout.py (Note: i want to create multiple pages so i figured it is more code efficient to use single a layout function). Using a numeric input box i want to update the df using a callback however i get an error saying that it does not recognise the dataframe. Is there a way to update the code so that the @callback recognises the argument of the layout function and updates the df.
Thank you in advance.

The variable arg1 is defined as a parameter of the function update_page and only exists in the scope of that function, it doesn't exist in the callback.
What you can do instead is to get the table's data using a State and work on that object directly (a State allows you to pass along extra values to the callback without firing it).
Also, you probably don't want to update the callback output when the data remain unchanged, which can be achieved by raising a PreventUpdate exception.
@callback(
    Output('table', 'data'),
    Input('my-numeric-input-1', 'value'),
    State('table', 'data'),
)
def updateTable(x, data):
    if x>0:
        # do stuff to `data`
        return data

    raise PreventUpdate


Thank you this works and is very helpful. I have a (hopefully) a quick follow up question. When i adjust the numeric input (x) to a value >1 and then adjust it back to 0 again the table does not reset to the original data table. Is there way to return to the original data table when the x returns to 0?

You can consider the case where x == 0 in the callback. If it's possible to reset the data given its current state and the value of x, just do that and return it to the output as for the condition x > 0. Otherwise, if there is no other way than restoring the original dataframe, you could add a Store in your layout to save the original data, and then add State('your-store', 'data') to the @callback decorator so that you can get the original data as an additional argument in the callback.

You might be thinking a global variable could do the trick so why bothering with a Store and a State ? Well it depends, in short : if you want multiple people to view the application at the same time and have independent sessions, you should definitely avoid it, see this for more info.
